# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_ajax' in Django 4 + highcharts

Tags: python-3.x, django, highcharts, django-wsgi

I'm trying to configure the display of graphs in Django using highcharts and I encounter this error:

> AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'

Code:

**views.py**

```
import random

from django.shortcuts import render
from highcharts.views import HighChartsBarView


class BarView(HighChartsBarView):
    title = 'Example Bar Chart'
    subtitle = 'my subtitle'
    categories = ['Orange', 'Bananas', 'Apples']
    chart_type = ''
    chart = {'zoomType': 'xy'}
    tooltip = {'shared': 'true'}
    legend = {'layout': 'horizontal', 'align': 'left',
              'floating': 'true', 'verticalAlign': 'top',
              'y': -10, 'borderColor': '#e3e3e3'}

    @property
    def series(self):
        result = []
        for name in ('Joe', 'Jack', 'William', 'Averell'):
            data = []

        for x in range(len(self.categories)):
            data.append(random.randint(0, 10))
        result.append({'name': name, "data": data})
        return result
```

**index.html**

```
{% % load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/highcharts/highcharts.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$.getJSON("{% url 'bar' %}", function(data) {
$('#container').highcharts(data);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea how to fix it

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django-braces does not support officially django4+ : https://pypi.org/project/django-braces/

Ths issue has already been fixed in the github, but not yet released.
https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/issues/288

You can install the github version with pip :

```
pip install git+https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces.git
```

I hope there is just this compatibility problem with django 4+ and it will be work

Comment: oh, this is really helped me! thx!
but now i get a new trouble - chart doesn't work. only text................................

Comment: i do not know highchart package. i can not help you for this part sorry